# SQL Query to compare attributes stored in the same database table side by side

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Let's say that we have a table like this:

```
entity_id attribute_name attribute_value
----------------------------------------
0         server         alpha
1         server         beta
0         priority       1
1         priority       2
1         comment        some comment
2         server         gamma
```

What would be the query, for PostgreSQL, that would give these results:

```
server    alpha     beta
priority  1         2
```

Note:

- we assume that we want to compare entities with id 0 and 1 only.
- if an attribute is not present for both entities it can be ignored

Comment: Are `server`, `alpha` and `beta` in the query results header captions, or the first row of data?

Comment: I would assume they are the first row as their id are also 0 and 1.

Comment: The answer is different in SQL Server, Postres, MySQL... you've been around long enough to know this. Please tag your question appropriately. That aside, it appears you might be using SQL to do display formatting. That's not the database's job. You would select these rows with a plain old `SELECT columns... FROM table` query, then in your application code display the stuff you want side-by-side side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
CREATE TABLE test1(entity_id int,attribute_name varchar(100), attribute_value varchar(100))
insert into test1
VALUES(0,'server','alpha'),
(1,'server','beta'),
(0,'priority','1'),
(1,'priority','2'),
(2,'server','gamma')

;WITH CTE as(
select attribute_name,(select STUFF((select ','+ attribute_value from test1 where entity_id in (0,1) and attribute_name=t1.attribute_name  for XML path('')),1,1,'') ) as colms
from test1 t1
where entity_id in (0,1)
group by attribute_name)

select attribute_name,LEFT(colms,CHARINDEX(',',colms,1)-1) as attr_value1,RIGHT(colms,len(colms)-CHARINDEX(',',colms,1)) as attr_value2 from CTE
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in TSQL:

```
SELECT T.attribute_name, A.attribute_value, B.attribute_value
FROM theTable T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT T0.attribute_value
    FROM theTable T0
    WHERE T0.entityId = 0 AND T0.attribute_name = T.attribute_name
) A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT T1.attribute_value
    FROM theTable T1
    WHERE T1.entityId = 1 AND T1.attribute_name = T.attribute_name
) B
```

You could add more `CROSS APPLY`s to include results for more entities.  If you aren't guaranteed to have an `attribute_value` for every entityId/name pair, you can replace it with `OUTER APPLY` (or use `INNER`/`LEFT JOIN`s equivalently)

Answer (score 0):

works at least in MySQL:

```
select attr_list.attribute_name, t0.attribute_value, t1.attribute_value
  from (select distinct attribute_name from tbl) as attr_list
  left join tbl as t0 on t0.attribute_name = attr_list.attribute_name 
   and t0.entity_id = 0
  left join tbl as t1 on t1.attribute_name = attr_list.attribute_name 
   and t1.entity_id = 1
```